# Python. Разделить строку без удаления разделителя

Tags: python, текст, split

Дано:

```
text = 'x^2-16x-64'
```

Вывод:

```
['x^2', '-16x', '-64']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение `(?=[-+])` сопоставляется со знаками плюс или минус но не перемещает текущую позицию. В результате разделитель не удаляется из строки:

```
re.split('(?=[-+])', 'x^3+x^2-16x-64')
```

> ```
> ['x^3', '+x^2', '-16x', '-64']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно есть способ получше, но в качестве примера

```
text = 'x^2-16x-64'
sp = '-'
tx = text.split(sp)
for i in range(1, len(tx)):
    tx[i] = sp + tx[i]
print(tx)
```

Вывод `['x^2', '-16x', '-64']`